table or external file to obtain a curve using lua?
I have two codes that allow me to draw the representative curve of a mathematical function. One code uses a table to store the coordinates of the points on the curve, the other uses an external file to store these same coordinates.
My question is why the second code seems faster. Is it because of my code? Can the first code be improved, or can another method be found?
With a table :
\RequirePackage{l3benchmark}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtEndDocument { \benchmark_toc: }
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
 function f(t0, t1, n)
 local tbl = {}
 for t = t0,t1,(t1-t0)/n  do
     x = math.sin (5*t)
     y = math.cos (3*t)
     table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
  end
  return table.concat (tbl)
end
}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
   \draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {\directlua{tex.print(f(0,2*math.pi,256))}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

With an external file
\RequirePackage{l3benchmark}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtEndDocument { \benchmark_toc: }
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
 function f(t0, t1, n)
  local out=assert(io.open("tmp.table","w"))
  for t = t0,t1,(t1-t0)/n  do
     x = math.sin (5*t)
     y = math.cos (3*t)
     out:write(x, " ", y, " i\string\n") 
   end
   out:close()
end
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
   \directlua{f(0,2*math.pi,256)}%
   \draw[red]  plot[smooth] file {tmp.table};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Just to provide a sense of the speeds involved: On my M2 MacBookAir, MacOS Sequoia 15.2, and MacTeX2024, the first document takes 0.611 s to compile, while the second takes 0.521 s.

@Mico I doubt it is accurate to 3dp unless you tested under properly controlled conditions and even then, maybe not. I'd say I get around 0.45s and around 0.38s, but the second is more variable (0.379, 0.388, 0.392 ...). I'm surprised mine is faster, than a mac though.

how is table.concat implemented? because if it is doing something like appending each entry to a string until the string contains them all, that will be expensive.

@cfr - It's just a MacBook Air, not a MacBook Pro...

@Mico yes, the comparison is with 7th generation i5. my hardware is old. and it was never in macbook pro territory to begin with.

I'm getting around 0.24 seconds for the first example and around 0.22 seconds for the second example, so I probably wouldn't worry to much about the speed difference here. But I can see a few different ways that could speed this up, so I'll try and write an answer later if I get time.

With a  MacBook Air M1 : 0.306 s with file  and 0.354 s with table.

@Mico Strange with MacBook Air M1 0.354 and 0.306

I was able to optimize the table solution a little bit, but the file-based solution is still faster:



Option
Description
Time (seconds)
Time (kiloperations)




1
“Table” (original)
0.0798
571


2
“File” (original)
0.0409
289


3
“Table” (optimized)
0.0544
385


4
“Insane”
0.225
1500



\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{l3benchmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn \g_benchmark_duration_target_fp { 5 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { benchmark } { b } {
    \benchmark:n {#1}
} {
    \clearpage
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \typeout{=== Option 1 ===}
    \directlua{
        function f(t0, t1, n)
            local tbl = {}
            for t = t0,t1,(t1-t0)/n  do
                x = math.sin (5*t)
                y = math.cos (3*t)
                table.insert (tbl, "("..x..","..y..")")
            end
            return table.concat (tbl)
        end
    }

    \begin{benchmark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {\directlua{tex.print(f(0,2*math.pi,256))}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{benchmark}

    \typeout{=== Option 2 ===}
    \directlua{
        function f(t0, t1, n)
            local out=assert(io.open("tmp.table","w"))
            for t = t0,t1,(t1-t0)/n  do
                x = math.sin (5*t)
                y = math.cos (3*t)
                out:write(x, " ", y, " i\string\n")
            end
            out:close()
        end
    }

    \begin{benchmark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \directlua{f(0,2*math.pi,256)}%
        \draw[red]  plot[smooth] file {tmp.table};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{benchmark}

    \typeout{=== Option 3 ===}
    \begin{luacode*}
        local allocate_table = lua.newtable
        local cos = math.cos
        local format = string.format
        local scan_float = token.scan_real
        local sin = math.sin
        local sprint = tex.sprint

        local FORMAT_STR = "(%.5f,%.5f)"

        local function myfunction()
            local t0 = scan_float()
            local t1 = scan_float()
            local n = scan_float()

            local out = allocate_table(n, 0)
            local delta = (t1 - t0) / n

            for i = 1, n do
                local t = t0 + (i * delta)
                local x = sin(5 * t)
                local y = cos(3 * t)
                out[i] = format(FORMAT_STR, x, y)
            end

            sprint(out)
        end

        local index = luatexbase.new_luafunction("myfunction")
        lua.get_functions_table()[index] = myfunction
        token.set_lua("myfunction", index, "global")
    \end{luacode*}

    \begin{benchmark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {\myfunction 0 6.283184 256 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{benchmark}

    \typeout{=== Option 4 ===}
    \begin{luacode*}
        local allocate_table = lua.newtable
        local codepoint = utf8.codepoint
        local codepoints = utf8.codes
        local collectgarbage = collectgarbage
        local cos = math.cos
        local create_token = token.create
        local format = string.format
        local new_token = token.create
        local new_token = token.new
        local rawget = rawget
        local scan_float = token.scan_real
        local sin = math.sin
        local write_tokens = token.put_next

        local ASSIGN_TOKS = token.command_id("assign_toks")
        local CATCODE_OTHER = 12
        local CS_TOKEN_FLAG = 0x1FFFFFFF
        local FORMAT_STR = "(%.5f,%.5f)"
        local INTEGER = codepoint "d"
        local THE = create_token("the")
        local TOKENS = codepoint "t"

        local codepoint_to_token = {}
        for char in ("+-.0123456789(),"):gmatch(".") do
            codepoint_to_token[codepoint(char)] = new_token(codepoint(char), CATCODE_OTHER)
        end

        local scratch_user_whatsit = node.new("whatsit", "user_defined")

        local function myfunction()
            collectgarbage("stop")
            local t0 = scan_float()
            local t1 = scan_float()
            local n = scan_float()

            local tokens = allocate_table(17 * n, 0)
            local delta = (t1 - t0) / n
            for i = 1, 3*n do
                local t = t0 + (i * delta)
                local x = sin(5 * t)
                local y = cos(3 * t)

                local len = #tokens
                for _, code in codepoints(format(FORMAT_STR, x, y)) do
                    len = len + 1
                    tokens[len] = rawget(codepoint_to_token, code)
                end
            end

            scratch_user_whatsit.type = TOKENS
            scratch_user_whatsit.value = tokens
            scratch_user_whatsit.type = INTEGER
            token.set_char("tmp", scratch_user_whatsit.value)
            local out = new_token(create_token("tmp").tok - 0x1FFFFFFF, ASSIGN_TOKS)

            write_tokens { THE, out }
            collectgarbage("restart")
            collectgarbage("step", 0)
        end

        local index = luatexbase.new_luafunction("myfunction")
        lua.get_functions_table()[index] = myfunction
        token.set_lua("myfunction", index, "global")
    \end{luacode*}

    \begin{benchmark}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {\myfunction 0 6.283184 256 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{benchmark}
\end{document}

To optimize the table solution, I

Scanned the input using token functions so that the Lua code doesn't need to be retokenized each run

Saved any used functions in local variables to avoid table lookups

Preallocated the output table to avoid resizing

Replaced table.insert with direct table assignments, which is slightly faster

Removed the unnecessary table.concat call


I ran option 3 through a profiler, and I found that (of the time spent
in the Lua function), 11% of the time was spent in the sine and cosine
functions, 11% was spent allocating the table, and 44% was spent in
tex.sprint. There might be a few more ways to speed this up, but I
doubt that it could be made much faster.
For the “insane” option, I tried some of the strategies that I typically
use to speed up LuaTeX code, but it actually made it run an order of
magnitude slower. I left this option in here in case someone is
interested in exploring it further (although there's probably not much
point in doing so).

Is the trick with the whatsit node is to speed things up by reducing the number of tokens pushed back to two?

@UdiFogiel Actually, looking through the LuaTeX source, it's probably the same (or maybe even slightly slower) than token.put_next in this case. The case where it would be faster would be if you needed to make a bunch of new tokens, since the whatsit method will accept a table of {cmd, chr} tokens while token.put_next only accepts the userdata tokens (which are marginally slower to create). The fastest solution would be token.fast_put_next, which I should probably submit upstream at some point.

Thanks !  interesting solution and thanks for noticing that table.concat was not necessary.

@MaxChernoff Finally, if we take into account the security involved in creating an external file, and the memory required for the table (I don't know if this is a problem for a large number of values), what is the best method?

@AlainMatthes There should be zero security implications to reading/writing to an external file, but filling the folder with a bunch of temporary files is mildly annoying, filesystem operations are quite slow on Windows, and the disk could be full/read-only, so I'd generally recommend the table solution over the file solution.
